# Memorylessness and its square

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

If we have that $T$ is a memoryless random variable, how do we know if $T^2$ is one too?

I am supposed to investigate the cases $T: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R_{\ge 0}}$ and
$T: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. I should mention here, that I know how that in that case T is exponentially or geometrically distributed. But how do I use this, to say something about $T^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you know that $X$ is exponential iff
$$
P(X>x)=\lambda\exp (\lambda x)\\
P(X^2>x) =P(X>\sqrt{x}) =\lambda\exp (\lambda \sqrt{x})
$$
So $X^2$ is never memoryless. Try to do the same with the discrete case.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's consider the continuous case (that is, $T:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$).

Suppose, for the sake of argument, that $T$ is memoryless AND $T^2$ is memoryless. Since $T^2$ is memoryless, for any $m,n>0$ we have
$$
P(T^2>m+n\mid T^2>m)=P(T^2>n).
$$
Now, we can rewrite this in terms of square roots:
$$
P(T>\sqrt{m+n}\mid T>\sqrt{m})=P(T>\sqrt{n})\tag{1}.
$$
What does memorylessness of $T$ tell us about this same probability? It says that
$$
\begin{align*}
P(T>\sqrt{m+n}\mid T>\sqrt{m})&=P(T>\sqrt{m}+(\sqrt{m+n}-\sqrt{m})\mid T>\sqrt{m})\\
&=P(T>\sqrt{m+n}-\sqrt{m}).\tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that for any $n,m>0$,
$$
P(T>\sqrt{n})=P(T>\sqrt{m+n}-\sqrt{m}).
$$
Note that $\sqrt{n}>\sqrt{m+n}-\sqrt{m}$ (as can be checked, for instance, by squaring both sides). So, we get that
$$
\begin{align*}
0&=P(T>\sqrt{m+n}-\sqrt{m})-P(T>\sqrt{n})
=P(T\in(\sqrt{m+n}-\sqrt{m},\sqrt{n}]).\tag{3}
\end{align*}
$$
This last property, however, is quite telling: you can make $\sqrt{n}$ as large as you want by choosing $n$ sufficiently large; with $n$ chosen, you can make $\sqrt{m+n}-\sqrt{m}$ as close to $0$ as you want by choosing $m$ sufficiently large.  What does this tell you about the random variable $T$?